# Display text in Text-box

Tags: javascript, onblur, onfocus

I am working around display text in Text-box & using following code

```
<input name="keyword" type="text" value="no spaces, or hyphens" onblur="this.value=(this.value=="") ? 'no spaces, or hyphens' : this.value;" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='no spaces, or hyphens') ? "" : this.value;" class="txtfield">
```

but when I click in text-box it gives following error:

> Timestamp: 7/17/2013 12:45:19 PM
>
> Error: SyntaxError: syntax error
>
> Line: 1, Column: 51

Source Code:

```
   this.value=(this.value=='no spaces, or hyphens') ?
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: The question is why the error occurs, obviously...

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use single quotes, or escape the double quotes.

**Single Quotes**

```
<input name="keyword" type="text" value="no spaces, or hyphens" onblur="this.value = (this.value == '') ? 'no spaces, or hyphens' : this.value;" onfocus="this.value = (this.value == 'no spaces, or hyphens') ? '' : this.value;" class="txtfield">
```

**Escaped Double Quotes**

```
<input name="keyword" type="text" value="no spaces, or hyphens" onblur="this.value = (this.value == \"\") ? \"no spaces, or hyphens\" : this.value;" onfocus="this.value = (this.value == \"no spaces, or hyphens\") ? \"\" : this.value;" class="txtfield">
```

The more elegant solution is clearly single quotes.

Comment: it gives me 

SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]  

this.value=(this.value==

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="keyword" type="text" value="no spaces, or hyphens" onblur="if(this.value =='') {this.value='no spaces, or hyphens'}" onfocus="if(this.value =='no spaces, or hyphens') {this.value=''}" class="txtfield">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quotation related error
your onblur attribute should be like this

```
onblur="this.value=(this.value=='') ? 'no spaces, or hyphens' : this.value;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Placeholder html5 attribute as following instedof javascript.

```
<input name="keyword" type="text" value="" placeholder="no spaces, or hyphens" class="txtfield">
```